# Is 576 bytes the safe size for UDP payload to eliminate fragmentation?

Tags: udp

The safe size of a datagram packet (considering the MTU such that packet will not get fragmented) is said to be 576 bytes for IPV4 and 1500 for IPV6.

1. Is this correct ?
2. If i am having a connection from my machine to a server in another country, two of which communicate using UDP, what is the maximum (safest) payload size i should have for the UDP packet, 1500 or 576 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. No. That's the safe size of the total IP packet.
2. 534.

Comment: Thanks. Was it (packet size 576) - (20 for IP header) - (8 for UDP header) - (14 for padding) = 534 ?

Comment: I'm assuming @EJP considered 14 bytes for the Ethernet II header. If so, then this is not considered in MTU. 2 should be 576 - 20 - 8 = 548 bytes.

Answer (score -1):

I found the real IP address in my local network. Then, I used recommendations at "www dot asus dot com/support/FAQ/1007914" in order to "check the best value of MTU(Maximum Transmission Unit) for the internet".

Comment: Is there some cogent reason why you can't post the URL as a URL?

Comment: @EJP I'd like to be on the safe side. I just send plain text.